# Poor Render Quality

Tags: rendering

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the quality is so bad for my render and why its pink? I know the viewport shading is how it will likely look in a render but will it affect the final render? I would like it to look like the photo on the right. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: On the right side in your screenshot you can see in the _Scene Properties_ under _Format_ that you have set dimensions of 1920 × 1080 pixels and a percentage of 1%, that's 19 × 11 pixels which is very small. I would suggest you increase the percentage and have look how the render changes. Then we can work on other problems if there are more.

Answer (score 0):

Pink usually means "Missing Textures". Be sure to pack all external files before you move your blend file to another location (Or store all project files in the same folder as the blend file, then move the whole folder).

From **File > External Data**, you can also *Report Missing Files*

[image]

Also, as Gordon Brinkmann already stated, your render resolution percentage is very low at 1%:
[image]